# Merging types in typescript (adding keys to an existing keyof type)

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types, keyof

If I have a typescript type consisting of keys:

```
const anObject = {value1: '1', value2: '2', value3: '3'}
type objectKeys = keyof typeof anObject
```

and then I wish to add keys to that type, while retaining the current keys, how do I go about doing that?
for example, if I wanted to add the keys 'get_value1', 'get_value2', 'get_value3' to the type 'objectKeys'

In the end, I want a type that looks like so:

```
type objectKeys = keyof anObject + 'get_value1', 'get_value2', 'get_value3'
```

without having to manually define the keys prefixed with 'get_', I understand that I can type out the keys to create this object - however that is not feasible for my use case.  I simply want to add some keys that may or may not exist to the type 'objectKeys'

I am also aware that I can create a generic or any type that allows for any key value, however I must know the actual key names.  It does not help me to allow for ANY key to be requested of the object, I need the existing keys + the ones I'd like to add.

Thanks for any help.

added for clarity:

```
const anObject = {val1: '1', val2: '2'}
type objectKeys = keyof typeof anObject

Object.keys(anObject).forEach(key => {
  const getAddition = `get_${key}`
  anObject[getAddition] = getAddition
})

// now I don't know whats next, how do I update objectKeys to include the 
// additions added in the forEach loop.

// What I really want is to not have to add the 'get' values to the object 
// at all, JUST to the type.  I want typechecking for the get values that 
// may or may not actually exist on the object.
```

hope thats clearerer and such.

Comment: As far as I read the specification for keyof and mapped types, there is no way to achieve this. Hope I'm wrong, but transforming key names is not a feature I've ever seen the typescript team demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for [concatenation of string literal types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12940): that is, you want to be able to take the string literal `"get_"` and another string literal like `"value1"`, and have TypeScript understand that if you concatenate strings of those types you get a string of the type `"get_value1"`.  Unfortunately, this feature does not exist as of TypeScript 2.4 (and probably won't exist in 2.5 or 2.6 either) .

So there's no way to do what you're asking for and maintain strict type safety.  You can, of course, relax the type safety and allow access for any unknown key:

```
const anObject = {val1: '1', val2: '2'};
const openObject: { [k: string]: any } & typeof anObject = anObject;
// replace "any" above with whatever type the get_XXX values are

Object.keys(openObject).forEach(key => {
  const getAddition = `get_${key}`
  openObject[getAddition] = getAddition
})
openObject.val1 = 1; // error, val1 is known to be a string
openObject.get_val1 = 1; // no error, get_val1 is any
openObject.gut_val4 = 1; // no error, oops, sorry
```

but you said you don't want to do that.

---

In that case, the suggestion I'd make is to give up on adding arbitrary keys to the object, and instead make the getters (or whatever they are) hang off a single `get` property, like so:

```
const anObject = { val1: '1', val2: '2' }

type AnObject = typeof anObject;
type ObjectKeys = keyof AnObject;
type GetAugmentedObject = AnObject & { get: Record<ObjectKeys, any> }; 
// replace "any" above with whatever type the get.XXX values are 

const get = {} as GetAugmentedObject['get'];
Object.keys(anObject).forEach((key: ObjectKeys) => get[key] = key);
const augmentedObject: GetAugmentedObject = { ...anObject, get }

augmentedObject.val1; // ok
augmentedObject.val2; // ok 
augmentedObject.get.val1; // ok
augmentedObject.get.val2; // ok
augmentedObject.get.val3; // error, no val3
augmentedObject.git.val1; // error, no git
```

This is not very different for the developer (`obj.get.val1` vs. `obj.get_val1`) but makes a big difference to TypeScript's ability to follow along.  If you're in any control of the code that's adding the keys I strongly advise doing something TypeScript-friendly like this, since you don't want to spend your time fighting with TypeScript if you don't have to.

---

Otherwise, if only string concatenation at the type level will work for you, and you feel your use case is compelling enough, maybe you should go to [the relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12940) and give it a  and describe why it's a must-have for you.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks much jcalz, great answer!  Your method for using the single get property will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

## 2020 Update

It's there in typescript **v4.1.0**

You probably need this - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals.

Here's an example where the property `id` must be `#` + `key`:

```
interface MyInterface<K extends string> {
    something: {
        [key in K]: { id: `#${key}` }
    }
}
```

So the following is correct:

```
let x: MyInterface<'foo'> = {
    something: {
        foo: { id: '#foo' }
    }
}
```

But this is incorrect:

```
let y: MyInterface<'foo'> = {
    something: {
        foo: { id: 'foo' }
    }
}
```